# macOS Catalina kernel debug

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

Anyone did Catalina kernel debug? I tried to copy the development edition of kernel from KDK folder(Catalina 536) to /System/Library/Kernels in the VMWare fusion target VM (Catalina beta8) according their readme file, anyhow that folder is readonly, you cannot copy any file there,
anyone has the solution?

One possible way is that reboot into recovery mode, but with VMWare fusion VM, it seems both latest version (Beta 8) and one vmx download from internet are not working, I tried both Cmd-R and 'reboot recovery' with nram settings.

Comment: Looks like the only way is to get into the recovery mode and copy the files there although it is almost impossible to do that with Catalina VM.

Comment: Does anyone notice Catalina removed the Display options menu on the application dock pop? in older version like Mojave and High Sierra, we can right click on the docked application, select options and then Displays (if hooked multiple monitors) to put the application Window on specific Display, how do we complete this in Catalina since the multiple display items removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remoutning the root file system using

$ mount -u -w /

Worked for me to be able to copy the new kernel over.  However my laptop is still slowly booting the debug kernel so I have not been able to verify end to end kernel debugging yet.